# Broken terminal output when running docker-compose with -T

Tags: docker-compose, terminal, zsh, tty

I have a script that I use to start commands on some docker-compose containers.

The script runs `docker-compose exec -T {container} {command}`.

I have to use the -T (Disable pseudo-TTY allocation. By default docker compose exec allocates a TTY) option because otherwise my precommit hook, which also runs this script, errors with a `panic: provided file is not a console`.

However when I run the script on my own terminal I get a broken output that looks like this :

```
run v1.22.10
            $ vite build
                        vite v2.7.13 building for production...
                                                               transforming...
                                                                              ✓ 378 modules transformed.
                                                                                                        rendering chunks...
                                                                                                                           public/front/assets/Inter-Thin.77d96c1c.woff2                   97.30 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                    public/front/assets/Inter-ExtraLight.b6cd094a.woff2             101.79 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              public/front/assets/Inter-ThinItalic.d82beee8.woff2             104.00 KiB
                                  public/front/assets/Inter-ExtraLightItalic.db229bf3.woff2       108.78 KiB
                                                                                                            public/front/assets/Inter-Light.36b86832.woff2                  101.89 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                      public/front/assets/Inter-LightItalic.737ac201.woff2            108.72 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                public/front/assets/Inter-Regular.d612f121.woff2                96.55 KiB
                   public/front/assets/Inter-Medium.1b498b95.woff2                 103.44 KiB
                                                                                             public/front/assets/Inter-Italic.900058df.woff2                 104.37 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                       public/front/assets/Inter-MediumItalic.81600858.woff2           109.55 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 public/front/assets/Inter-SemiBold.15226129.woff2               103.32 KiB
     public/front/assets/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.3b6df7d0.woff2         109.42 KiB
                                                                               public/front/assets/Inter-BoldItalic.3f211964.woff2             109.19 KiB
                                                                                                                                                         public/front/assets/Inter-Bold.c63158ba.woff2                   103.65 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   public/front/assets/Inter-ExtraBoldItalic.cf6b1d6c.woff2        109.09 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             public/front/assets/Inter-ExtraBold.307d9809.woff2              103.62 KiB
                                                                 public/front/assets/Inter-Black.fc10113c.woff2                  100.46 KiB
                                                                                                                                           public/front/assets/Inter-BlackItalic.bc80081d.woff2            106.20 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     public/front/assets/TRYVesterbro-Light.59d4e0df.woff2           134.08 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               public/front/assets/TRYVesterbro-Regular.cf9a26a9.woff2         139.92 KiB
                                                   public/front/assets/TRYVesterbro-Medium.116a42a4.woff2          142.17 KiB
                                                                                                                             public/front/assets/TRYVesterbro-Bold.ac6caaee.woff2            144.62 KiB
                                                                                                                                                                                                       public/front/assets/TRYVesterbro-ExtraBold.9be0564d.woff2       142.90 KiB
```

Without -T the output is fine (every line is aligned correctly) but the hook will not work with the previously stated error.

If that's relevant I use zsh for my shell but I tried running in bash and it doesn't solve the issue either.

Is there any way to fix the terminal output while retaining -T in docker-compose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after investigating I found that the output only contained `\n` and not `\n\r`. The missing `\r` is the reason the output skips a line but doesn't go back to the start (carriage return).

I made a simple bash function that I added to my `.zshrc` (you can add it to your `.bashrc` too).

```sh
clout() {
  $@ | sed 's/$/\r/'
}
```

Use it like this

`clout your_command args`

This function pipes the output of your command and adds a `\r` when it sees a `\n`.

This is the best solution I found. I am still open to better solutions if someone has one.